# Bash script not working when using Nginx + Gunicorn, but otherwise it is fine

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a quick question. So I have a flask app that is being hosted by nginx + gunicorn. It works just fine when running the Flask app by itself or just with gunicorn, but when using it with nginx, some of my bash scripts begin to not work.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh=`which ssh`
scp=`which scp`
opssh=/usr/bin/opssh
opscp=/usr/bin/opscp
opsite=/usr/bin/opsite
ssh_opts1=-A

sites=$(ssh -A someServer 'list sites')

for i in "$sites"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

And when I check the status of my service, it gives me back this error:

```
gunicorn[28629]: ./get_list_of_sites.sh: line 3: which: command not found
gunicorn[28629]: ./get_list_of_sites.sh: line 4: which: command not found
```

I have been searching everywhere to find a solution for why it is not finding the which command. My suspicion is that nginx proxies it to a "different" environment and maybe that is why it is not seeing the which command? If anyone has any idea about this, it would be very appreciated. Also attached below is my nginx setup if that matters.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some_server;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/aalred/WebScriptsAPI/webHub.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's easy to test your theory. Try a full path. E.g., `/usr/bin/which`

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I did, it still did not work down when I actually ssh to the server. I want to know how I would go about fixing it because listing hard paths seems much more a bandaid than a solution.